# How can I make Syntastic load a different checker based on existance of files in root?

Tags: vim, jshint, vim-plugin, syntastic, eslint

At work we use a different syntax checker than I do when working on open source. Is there a way to have [`Syntastic`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) specify a default checker, and change checkers if an `rc` file is found at the project root?

Example: if `.eslintrc` is found use [`eslint`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint). If no `.eslintrc` is found, use [`standard`](https://github.com/feross/standard).

Thanks!

edit: also opened an issue on [scrooloose/syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1327).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript let b:syntastic_checkers = findfile('.eslintrc', '.;') != '' ? ['eslint'] : ['standard']
```

**Edit:** Upon request, explanation of how this works:

- `autocmd FileType javascript` - run the following stuff every time the `filetype` of a buffer is set to `javascript` (that is, normally once per buffer)
- `b:syntastic_checkers` list of checkers enabled for the current buffer, overriding `g:syntastic_javascript_checkers`
- `findfile('.eslintrc', ...)` - find a file named `.eslintrc` ...
- `.;` - ... in the current directory and upwards
- `!= '' ?` - if found...
- `['eslint']` - ... set `b:syntastic_checkers` to `['eslint']`
- `: ['standard']` - ... otherwise set it to `['standard']`

Magic, I tell ya.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation as to how this command works?

Comment: @lcd047 could you elaborate on how to make it use a local binary instead of `standard`?

Comment: @dcousens: I never said you could make it use an arbitrary local binary instead of `standard`.

Comment: @lcd047 sure.  So I guess that means you're not aware of a way to make it do that?

Comment: @dcousens If you have a question, please ask it in a separate post.  If you feel that your question doesn't belong on SO, syntastic issue tracker is [this way](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option, which has wider application than just this question, is to add the following to your .vimrc file:

```
if findfile('.lvimrc','.') != ''
    source .lvimrc
endif
```

Then in the directory where you want some different behavior, just add a '.lvimrc' file with the syntastic option that you want for that directory.